# Not able to read XML string in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have created a XML string and Looping that to get value. But its not entering in foreach loop. But in my other code same loop code is working.
my code is :

XML string:

```
<SuggestedReadings>
  <Suggestion Text="Customer Centricity" Link="http://wdp.wharton.upenn.edu/book/customer-centricity/?utm_source=Coursera&utm_medium=Web&utm_campaign=custcent" SuggBy="Pete Fader�s" />
  <Suggestion Text="Global Brand Power" Link="http://wdp.wharton.upenn.edu/books/global-brand-power/?utm_source=Coursera&utm_medium=Web&utm_campaign=glbrpower" SuggBy="Barbara Kahn�s" />
</SuggestedReadings>
```

Code Is:

```
string str = CD.SRList.Replace("&", "&amp;");
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(str);

XmlNode SuggestionListNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/SuggestedReadings/Suggestion");
foreach (XmlNode node in SuggestionListNode)
{
   COURSESUGGESTEDREADING CSR = new COURSESUGGESTEDREADING();
   var s = db.COURSESUGGESTEDREADINGS.OrderByDescending(o => o.SRID);
   CSR.SRID = (s == null ? 0 : s.FirstOrDefault().SRID) + 1;
   CSR.COURSEID = LibId;
   CSR.TEXT = node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Text").Value;
   CSR.LINK = node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Link").Value; ;
   CSR.SUGBY = node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("SuggBy").Value; ;
   CSR.ACTIVEFLAG = "Y";
   CSR.CREATEDBY = CD.CreatedBy;
   CSR.CREATEDDATE = DateTime.Now;
   db.COURSESUGGESTEDREADINGS.Add(CSR);
}
```

Comment: You're calling `SelectSingleNode` - but you're trying to select *multiple* nodes. (As an aside, I'd urge you to move to LINQ to XML if you can... it's a much nicer API.)

Comment: @JonSkeet i have no idea of LINQ to XML. So its better Post an example based on above code.

Comment: Well you can search for a LINQ to XML tutorial to get you started, if you're interested. But if you really want to stick to XmlDocument, then try changing the `SelectSingleNode` call to a rather more suitable one...

Comment: You probably meant 
            XmlNodeList SuggestionListNode = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/SuggestedReadings/Suggestion");

Comment: Definitely look into LINQ to XML if you have time.  It's much easier to use and quite powerful.

Comment: @Raghubar I suspect you wrote `SelectSingleNode` by accident. I think we should close this question as a typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `SelectNodes`, not `SelectSingleNode`, since you are trying to get multiple rows out of the XML document.

Use this:

```
XmlNodeList SuggestionListNode = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Suggestion");
foreach (XmlNode node in SuggestionListNode)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");
var xmlData = from lv1 in xdoc.Descendants("Suggestion")
           select new { 
               Text = lv1.Attribute("Text").Value,
               Link = lv1.Attribute("Link").Value,
               SuggBy = lv1.Attribute("SuggBy").Value
           };
foreach (var item in xmlData){
     // your logic here
}